# Find $gf(x)$ in terms of $h$ and $k$ for the functions $f(x) = 5x - 1$, $g(x) = hx + k$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

> Find $gf(x)$ in terms of $h$ and $k$.
> \begin{align*}
> f(x) & = 5x - 1\\
> g(x) & = hx + 2k
> \end{align*}

What I've tried:
\begin{align*}
g(5x-1) & = h(5x-1)+2k\\
        & = 5hx-h+2k
\end{align*}
My answer is $gf(x) = 5hx-h+2k$.  However, when I checked the answer, it is $gf(x) = 5hk-h+2k$.

I don't know if its my answer that's wrong or the one in my textbook that is wrong. Could anyone help?

Comment: Your answer of $(g\circ f)(x)=5hx-h+2k$ is correct.

Comment: oh alright, thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It might be worth identifying what your textbook is. If it is a professionally published work, it can be added to an errata list. More to the point, MathStackExchange will now have a record of this for the next time someone has the same problem as you with the same book,